# Python Traits- call function at parent level, when item modified in a List

Tags: python, events, enthought, traits

I am trying to use Traits to monitor and perform some aggregating/statistical functions on a List.  To simplify the problem, lets say I have a "TestScore" object, which consists of a name, a score, and a quartile.  I then have a "TestBundle" which consists of a List of TestScore.  If a score is updated for one of the TestScore objects, I want to call some functionality that will re-calculate the quartile for all TestScore objects in the list.  I have tried the following:

```
from traits.api import \
    Float, List, HasTraits, Str, on_trait_change

class TestResult(HasTraits):
    name = Str
    score = Float
    quartile = Float

class TestBundle(HasTraits):
    tests = List(TestResult)

    @on_trait_change('tests[]')
    def update_quartiles(self):
        # Code to go over all tests and update the quartile based
        # on score
        print "Updating Quartiles"
```

However this only seems to fire when a TestScore is added or removed from the TestBundle.tests list.  Is there a way to fire whenever one of the constituents of tests is modified?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the answer.  You can extend the name to include the child parameter names that need to be monitored.  This is actually ideal in my case, as I only want to fire the "update_quartiles" when the score value is changed.  It can be done like so:

```
from traits.api import \
    Float, List, HasTraits, Str, on_trait_change

class TestResult(HasTraits):
    name = Str
    score = Float
    quartile = Float

class TestBundle(HasTraits):
    tests = List(TestResult)

    @on_trait_change('tests.score')
    def update_quartiles(self):
        # Code to go over all tests and update the quartile based
        # on score
        print "Updating Quartiles"
```

Then if any scores are changed, or new TestResults are added, TestBundle.update_quartiles() is executed.